# alternate the display of module_blogsitepost

Tags: business-catalyst

How can I display the `{module_blogsitepost}` according to what I want? For example I have a list of post in blog module how can I display in reverse or make the old post make it to first display when I call the `{module_blogsitepost}`. I tried to change their release date but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve a custom display of `{module_blogsitepost}` using Liquid markup using the following:

```
{module_blogsitepost rowCount="X" collection="custom-collection-name" template=""}
```

(Where "rowCount" is the number of blog posts displayed).

For more info on this, refer to the [Business Catalyst documentation on {module_blogsitepost}](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/modules/blogs/module_blogsitepost.html).

The above markup puts all the data available in `{module_blogsitepost}` into a collection called "custom-collection-name". You can view the data stored in "custom-collection-name" using `<pre> {{ custom-collection-name | json }} </pre>` (place this on your page).

Here is an example of how to create your own custom display of the module, specifically in reverse order. Use the keyword **reversed**:

```
{% for item in custom-collection-name.items reversed -%}

    <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{item.title}}</h2>
        <div class="post-details">
            {{item.author}} | {{item.date}}
        </div>
        <div class="post-body">
            {{item/body}}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor -%}
```

**Note:** It is important to realise that the Liquid output of this module does not include the truncated blog post like {module_blogsitepost} does by default. The above will output the entire blog post and you will need to look at ways to truncate the data contained in `{{item.body}}`.

You will most likely want to manipulate the output of {{item.date}} as well. See the [Business Catalyst documentation on Date Switches](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/liquid/filters.html#Dateswitches).